# How can I remove an error from my HTML file, while implementing the method in ngClass?

Tags: angular, ng-class

**I don't know where I'm getting wrong.**

1. app.component.html

   ```
   <div [ngClass]="stylemethodName();"> ngClass with method </div>
   ```
2. app.component.ts

   ```
   export class AppComponent {
   title = 'Simple_CRM_App';

    stylemethodName(){

       return 'c3';

     }
   }
   ```
3. app.component.scss

   ```
    .c3 {
           color:red;
     }
   ```

I'm getting an error in the template app component.
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` from the expression:

```
<div [ngClass]="stylemethodName()"> ngClass with method </div>
```

Also, it is really bad practice when you are returning values from the function. That function will be triggered on each Change Detection. Try to implement a logic in template directly.

Comment: Yes, it works !! I will implement logic in the template directly.

Comment: I am glad it worked. Consider also accepting my answer if it helped you.